# PHP built html table

Tags: php, html, math, html-table

I'm using the code below to build a table, but because the values in my database table are constantly incrementing, I'm doing some math to work out differences in values (numerically) but this has screwed up the table layout somehow. I've included a screenshot so you can see that the first row beneath the table header is just not right.

`$column` is a `$_GET` value from the user.

```
    $sql = "select * from (select * from mash order by tstamp desc limit 10) s order by s.id";
                   $result = mysql_query($sql);
                   $previous = 0;
                   $firstRun = true;
                   echo "<table id='dataTable' border='1'>";
                   echo "<tr><th>Date</th>
                         <th>Value</th></tr>";
                   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                        $difference = $row[$column] - $previous;
                        if (!$firstRun)
                        echo "<tr><td>" . date("G:i:s", strtotime($row["tstamp"])) . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $difference . "</td></tr>";
                        $previous = $row[$column];
                        $firstRun = false;
                   }
              echo "</table>";
```

[image]

My question: Can anyone spot from the code, why the first row would come out like this?

Comment: Is this live? It might be good to see what HTML it produces

Comment: @Chris, afraid not fella,its sensitive client data, thats why i'm limited to putting a screenshot :(

Comment: What do you want to do "if (!$firstRun)" ?? In this case you're just removing the start of the line and the first cell, that's why your first line is messed up

Comment: If i have 3 values: 1,3,4 then you havent got anything before 1 to do the math with, so it misses the first calculation so i get expected results

Comment: can you try `$previous = "0"` ? when you use `$previous = 0` it's a boolen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem comes from this line:

```
 if (!$firstRun)
   echo "<tr><td>" . date("G:i:s", strtotime($row["tstamp"])) . "</td>";
```

If you don't want to display the first line, use the brackets:

```
 if (!$firstRun){
   echo "<tr><td>" . date("G:i:s", strtotime($row["tstamp"])) . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $difference . "</td></tr>";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's your "if" statement. It doesn't echo anything on the first run, so the starting tr and td don't get echoed, so you end up with an incorrect row (ended with the /tr tag) containing only a single td value. Did you mean to put brackets around the two echo statements so that they only happen when firstrun is false?

Answer (score 0):

first of all, where is `$column` defined ?

```
$difference = $row[$column] - $previous;
```

second, this is only executed as of the second iteration

```
if (!$firstRun)
echo "<tr><td>" . date("G:i:s", strtotime($row["tstamp"])) . "</td>";
```

This means that the first time in the while loop, you are not creating the table row `<tr>` , although I'm guessing the browser is able to "fix" the missing tag, but this would be the reason why `-32722` appears in the first column.

Comment: $column is a $_GET value from the user. Read the question dude